# How to send file from form input to server

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on this website where I need to send the file from my form to the server.

The part of the file input HTML :

```
<div class="custom-file">
            <input id="inputGroupFile03" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile03" id='labelnextInput'>Sélectionnez un fichier</label>
</div>
```

And the PHP I was working on :

```
<?php

$targetdir = '/uploads/';


if(isset($_FILES['namefile']['name'])){
    $target_file = $targetdir . basename($_FILES['nameFile']['name']);
};

$uploadOk = 1;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['nameFile']['tmp_name']);
    
    if($check != False){
        echo 'Ce fichier est une image -' . $check['mime'] . '.';
    }else{
        echo 'Type de ficher incorrect';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

header('Location: /aftersubmit.html');

?>
```

When the form is submitted, the PHP script runs and redirects me to the aftersubmit.html page but the file in the form is not in the /uploads/ folder and appears nowhere.

Thanks !

Comment: Show us the `<form.....>`  tag please

Comment: ```<form method="GET" action ='/php/fileToServer.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulaireUpload">``` the submit is on the submit button and a JS script

Comment: Make the method `method="post"` `get` does not work when moving files

Comment: Your file input field needs a `name` attribute

Comment: Learn how to upload here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Ok so I used the code you sent me but now I have an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /homepages/4/d826779636/htdocs/uploads/fileToServer.php on line 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check something like this:

```
<div class="custom-file">
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sélectionnez un fichier</button>
                </form>
</div>
```

files[] can upload more than one files, and do submit coding for e.g.

```
$folderDestination = '../uploads/';  // ../ or ./ depends on your situation
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if(file_exists($folderDestination)) 
  {
    if(is_writable($folderDestination)) {
        $files = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']);
        $totalFiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        $fileUploaded = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$totalFiles;$i++)
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $fileDestination = $folderDestination.'/'.$fileName;
            if($ext == 'XML' or $ext == 'PNG') // You can check if file has proper extension
            {
                // upload file
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $folderDestination.'/'.$fileName);
                $fileUploaded[] = $fileName;
                // do echo                
                echo $fileName.' uploaded <span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">correctly</span>';  
                // or header action
                // header("Location: aftersubmit.php?info=uploadOK");                  
            } else { echo '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">'. $fileName .' uploaded error</span>'; } 
            }
        } else { header("Location: aftersubmit.php?info=folderNotExists"); }  
    } else { header("Location: aftersubmit.php?info=folderIsNotWritable"); }
}
```

ofc change your aftersubmit.html to php. Sometimes you need to check if folder exists and if its writable and that is done here. Its working on my side. Change it for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can only submit files using POST (and methods not supported by forms) requests. They can't be encoded in the URL for a GET request (and the `enctype` attribute has no effect on a GET form). Change the method of your form element.

Comment: Even when I use the POST method it still doesnt work